# I would like to extend or override the TerminalNode object in a parse tree

Tags: c#, antlr4

I am working on a code generator in C# using ANTLR4. It works, but I am doing some things at a higher level than TerminalNode, that I think should be handled in TerminalNode.

Right now, I have an Identifier rule that might, for example, have the GetText() value, "myCollection.First.Name" and having child TerminalNodes of "myCollection", ".", "First", ".", "Name" ... [Note that my domain language is not C# or Java or C++ - it's a custom syntax.]

I currently perform a mapping from the IdentifierContext to the domain model that the code will manipulate, where I think it would be easier to implement and understand if that mapping was done at the TerminalNode level, like this:

```
"myCollection" --> An identifier for an object that lives in the top level scope.
"." --> Descend into the scope of "myCollection".
"First" --> an identifier for an object that lives in "myCollection"'s scope
"." --> Descend into the scope of "First".
"Name" --> an identifier for an object that lives in "First"'s scope
```

I've been unable to find a way to do this, and I'm not yet sure that creating a custom Token and TokenFactory is the right way to go. It seems as though that would put into the lexer, what ought to reside in the parser.

Help?

P.S. I have "The Definitive Antlr4 Reference," so while it does not seem so far to be, if the answer is in there please provide me a pointer to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, while it's not what I think is the best way, due to required expedience, I've pursued this by creating a custom token and token factory as follows:

in the parsing namespace, I created a custom token:

```
public class VToken : CommonToken
{

    public IModelTreeNode ModelTreeNode;
    public bool IsRecognized;
    public string[] Completions;

    public VToken(int type, String text) : base(type, text)
    {
    }

    public VToken(Tuple<ITokenSource, ICharStream> source, int type,
        int channel, int start, int stop) : base(source, type, channel, start, stop)
    {
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "VToken : " + Text;
    }
}
```

Then I created a custom token factory (also in the parsing namespace)

```
public class VTokenFactory : ITokenFactory
{
    public static readonly ITokenFactory Default = (ITokenFactory)new VTokenFactory();

    protected internal readonly bool copyText;

    public VTokenFactory(bool copyText)
    {
        this.copyText = copyText;
    }

    public VTokenFactory()
        : this(false)
    {
    }

    public virtual VToken Create(Tuple<ITokenSource, ICharStream> source, int type, string text, int channel, int start, int stop, int line, int charPositionInLine)
    {
        VToken myToken = new VToken(source, type, channel, start, stop)
        {
            Line = line,
            Column = charPositionInLine
        };

        if (text != null)myToken.Text = text;
        else if (this.copyText && source.Item2 != null) myToken.Text = source.Item2.GetText(Interval.Of(start, stop));
        return myToken;
    }

    IToken ITokenFactory.Create(Tuple<ITokenSource, ICharStream> source, int type, string text, int channel, int start, int stop, int line, int charPositionInLine)
    {
        return (IToken)this.Create(source, type, text, channel, start, stop, line, charPositionInLine);
    }

    public virtual VToken Create(int type, string text)
    {
        return new VToken(type, text);
    }

    IToken ITokenFactory.Create(int type, string text)
    {
        return (IToken)this.Create(type, text);
    }
}
```

And finally, altered the parser creation as follows:

```
VLexer lexer = new VLexer(input);
VTokenFactory factory = new VTokenFactory(); // <-- added
lexer.TokenFactory = factory;                // <-- added
CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
VParser parser = new VParser(tokens);
```

And when I'm processing rules, I access the new fields through:

```
((VToken)context.children[0].Payload).Completions
((VToken)context.children[0].Payload).IsRecognized
((VToken)context.children[0].Payload).ModelTreeNode
```

Comment: Note: this works, but as I said, doesn't feel like it's architecturally the "right" place to put it. Any suggestions would still be quite welcome.